# Struggling with dynamically allocate a new integer array

Tags: c++

I need to Pass the array to a function.  Within the function, dynamically allocate a new integer array.  Pro-grammatically assign the value from the original array to the new array in reverse order such that the first entry in the original array becomes the fifth entry in the new array, the second entry in the original array becomes the fourth entry in the new array, and so on.  Display the contents of the new array in the function.  Do not return the new array from the function.  Do not change the contents of the original array.  Use a pointer to an array, i.e., use dereferencing, when assigning and displaying the contents of the new array.  The dynamically allocated array will be deleted.

Below is sort of the frame work of what I got going now but am stumped and not sure how to proceed.

The first one displays the array in order they are in the array but am struggling with how I would passing it off to the the other function and then display in revers order. I think I was close at one point but the more I muddled with it I think I actually made it worse and got further away from what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void dispArr(int *, int);
void dispArrRev(int *, int);

void main()
{

    int arrA[5] = { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 };

    dispArr(arrA, 5);
    dispArrRev(arrA, 5);


    system("pause");
    return;
}

void dispArr(int *val, int size)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
        cout << x << " = " << *(val + x) << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    return;
}

void dispArrRev(int *val, int size)  //call by pointer
{
    //Stare at white space until light bulb appears :S :| 
}
```

Comment: You can change `for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)` to go through the array in reverse order

Comment: @appleapple the stipulation seems to include making a dynamic array inside the function

Comment: "I need to Pass the array to a function." - OK so far, function takes `int *val`.  "Within the function, dynamically allocate a new integer array."  - ok, your turn. Write the code to dynamically allocate an integer array.

Comment: @M.M oh your are right! I was misleading by OP's `dispArr`  code :P

Comment: You will make it easier for everybody if you post actual code that have problems. Your sample doesn't even try to allocate an array. If you are asking how to allocate an array of integers, then the answer is: int *arr = new int[size];

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, you can store it as it is, but represented it in reverse order, e.g.:

```
void dispArrRev(int *val, int size)
{
    for (int x = size-1; x >0; x--)
    {
        cout << x << " = " << *(val + x) << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    return;
}
```

If you must allocate and deallocate an array inside the function, then your code should be (Note that I did not add code to check if new_array has been allocated) :

```
void dispArrRev(int *val, int size)
{
    int *new_array=new int[size];
    for (int x = size-1; x >0; x--)
    {
        new_array[size-x-1]=*(val + x);
    }
    dispArr(new_array,size);
    delete [] new_array;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I was struggling with 1 defining the dynamic array and 2 display in reverse order. When I did the for loop before I kept getting an infinite loop of a bunch of negative weird numbers. I was doing

 for (int x = 0;x < size;x--)
 {
  cout << x << " = " << *(val + x) << endl;
 }
 cout << endl;

apologize on the formatting struggling even to post comments apparently :S